# adb does not show path where file is pushed after using adb push

Tags: android, adb

I have recently updated to Adb version 1.0.39.
After updating , when I use adb push command to push, after pushing it does not show the remote path file is actually pushed.

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\__tmp>adb push file1.txt /sdcard/

file1.txt: 1 file pushed.
```

However, in earlier version 1.0.31, it used to show the path where it is exactly pushed. like pushed to /sdcard/ like this.

Is it possible to enable some kind of logging here ?

Comment: If you do not know where your pushed file ends up at - you probably should not be pushing it.

Answer (score 1):

`adb` client never *used to show the path where it is exactly pushed*. It only used to print the location it asked the `adbd` to store the pushed file at. But it never had any means of actually knowing the actual location. So when simple guessing stopped working reliably in later Android versions they just removed the print out.